# Using "omega" for type "N"

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

For my research, I wrote a bunch of functions in Coq for the type `nat` and proved they are correct. Now I need to write the same functions for the type `N` but proving their correctness seems like a pain since the `omega` tactic does not work for this type. Is there an alternative for `omega` on `N`?

So far I have looked at the library `Nnat` and found several useful translation from `N` to `nat` and vice versa. If no `omega` alternative exists, is there a tactic to quickly transform a goal in `N` to `nat` and use `omega` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lia` tactic, available in the `Lia` module, seems to work with `N`.